# How to point subdomain from one server to public_html/folder on my server

Tags: networking, subdomain

I have domain on one server mydomain.com
There is subdomain on that server subdomain.mydomain.com
That subdomain should point to other server to
public_html/myfolder.
Please advise how to do that.

Comment: You need to try yourself first and then come here to ask if you encounter any issues.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to edit/create a Virtualhost file for your subdomain. The virtualhost for Apache should look like bellow.

```
<VirtualHost XX.XX.XX.XX>
    DocumentRoot "/www/public_html"
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    ServerAlias www.subdomain.example.com

    # Other directives here ...

</VirtualHost>
```

**Edit:** Name based virtual hosting.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
DocumentRoot /www/public_html/main_website
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example2.com
DocumentRoot /www/public_html/subdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

**NginX**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/public_html/subdomain;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name subdomain.example.com www.subdomain.example.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if the  OP is using nginx? Or if they are using name based virtual hosting ?